# Accessing last values of multilevel Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string input that I convert into a Dictionary. Usually the resulting Dictionary has multiple levels, i.e. a nested structure.

I would like to access its "leaf" elements, independently from the number of levels of the Dictionary.

Example:

```
# inputs arriving to my code from external users
input1 = "{'country':{'name':'Italy', 'region':'Europe'}}"
input2 = "{'country':{'first_country':{'name':'Italy', 'region':'Europe'}, 'second_country':{'name':'France', 'region':'Europe'}}}"

import ast
dict1 = ast.literal_eval(input1)
dict2 = ast.literal_eval(input2)

print(dict1)
>>> {'country': {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}}

print(dict2)
>>> {'country': {'first_country': {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}, 'second_country': {'name': 'France', 'region': 'Europe'}}}
```

Is there a way to access the fields `name` and `region`, independently from the passed dictionary?

I cannot know in advance the number of dictionary levels, as they depend from the input entered by external users. I would like to access the last level of the dictionary, independently from its levels.

**EDIT**

Let the code speak. The following code does what I want, but something in my brain suggests me avoiding the `exec` statement.

```
#swap Italy country with Germany, independently from the passed dictionary
def levels(d):
    return max(count(v) if isinstance(v,dict) else 0 for v in d.values()) + 1

def swapCountry(inputDict):
    if levels(inputDict) == 2:
        path = "dict1['country']['name']"
    elif levels(inputDict) == 3:
        path = "dict2['country']['first_country']['name']"

    exec('{} = "Germany"'.format(path))
```

Therfore:

```
swapCountry(dict1)
print(dict1)
>>> {'country': {'name': 'Germany', 'region': 'Europe'}}

swapCountry(dict2)
print(dict2)
>>> {{'country': {'first_country': {'name': 'Germany', 'region': 'Europe'}, 'second_country': {'name': 'France', 'region': 'Europe'}}}
```

Comment: why isn't the value of `country` a list `[{'name':'Italy', 'region':'Europe'}, {'name':'France', 'region':'Europe'}]`

Comment: Hi depperm, why it should be?

Comment: it would allow `country` to be a lot more dynamic by allowing multiple countries to be added without adding extra keys, and it could be sorted/ordered

Comment: Yeah, but i don't have to add country. I take data in input :) just want to develop code that works independently form the dictionary levels

Comment: can you clarify what you want, the question isn't very clear

Comment: I think you need to use Regular expression operations.

Comment: @deppern, edited; yaho: why regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
import ast

def get_leafs(d):
    res = [leaf for v in d.values() if isinstance(v, dict) for leaf in get_leafs(v)]
    if not res:
        res = [d]
    return res

# inputs arriving to my code from external users
input1 = "{'country':{'name':'Italy', 'region':'Europe'}}"
input2 = "{'country':{'first_country':{'name':'Italy', 'region':'Europe'}, 'second_country':{'name':'France', 'region':'Europe'}}}"
dict1 = ast.literal_eval(input1)
dict2 = ast.literal_eval(input2)

print(get_leafs(dict1))
# [{'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}]
print(get_leafs(dict2))
# [{'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}, {'name': 'France', 'region': 'Europe'}]
```

If you prefer to do it with a generator:

```
def get_leafs_gen(d):
    if any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in d.values()):
        yield from (leaf for v in d.values() if isinstance(v, dict) for leaf in get_leafs(v))
    else:
        yield d

print(*get_leafs_gen(dict1))
# {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}
print(*get_leafs_gen(dict2))
# {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'} {'name': 'France', 'region': 'Europe'}
```

EDIT: If you prefer to have the keys that take you to each leaf, you can have something like this:

```
def get_leaf_keys_gen(d):
    if any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in d.values()):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                for leaf_key in get_leaf_keys_gen(v):
                    yield (k,) + leaf_key
    else:
        yield ()

print(*get_leaf_keys_gen(dict1))
# ('country',)
print(*get_leaf_keys_gen(dict2))
# ('country', 'first_country') ('country', 'second_country')
```

Then to actually retrieve the leaves:

```
def get_from_multikey(d, key):
    if not key:
        return d
    else:
        return get_from_multikey(d[key[0]], key[1:])

print(*(get_from_multikey(dict1, key) for key in get_leaf_keys_gen(dict1)))
# {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'}
print(*(get_from_multikey(dict2, key) for key in get_leaf_keys_gen(dict2)))
# {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe'} {'name': 'France', 'region': 'Europe'}
```

EDIT 2: Added yet another alternative to apply a visitor function to each leaf:

```
def visit_leaves(d, visitor):
    if any(isinstance(v, dict) for v in d.values()):
        for v in d.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                visit_leaves(v, visitor)
    else:
        visitor(d)

# Adds a new item 'n' to every leaf in dict1
visit_leaves(dict1, lambda leaf: leaf.setdefault('n', 0))
print(dict1)
# {'country': {'name': 'Italy', 'region': 'Europe', 'n': 0}}

# Removes 'region' from every leaf in dict2
visit_leaves(dict2, lambda leaf: leaf.pop('region', None))
print(dict2)
# {'country': {'first_country': {'name': 'Italy'}, 'second_country': {'name': 'France'}}}
```

Comment: Thank you jdehesa. Probably I am wrong, but in this way I can only "see" which are the leaf elements; but I don't have access to them, in order to modify them. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bernheart Well really you are getting the leaf dicts themselves, not copies of them, so if you modify them they will be modified in the original objects too. I'm not sure what you mean by "access" to them otherwise... You could get the sequence of keys that would give you each leaf I suppose.

Comment: @Bernheart I added a variation to get leaf keys.

Comment: yes I need to modify the original dict. Maybe in this case the code could be simplified? Thank you

Comment: @Bernheart As I said, the result you get would allow you to make changes on the original dicts, as the code stands. If you want to apply some function to each leaf, I have added a function for that. If none of these solve your problem, please try to specifically point out why and what exactly you need.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding some code to explain better what I mean.